Radon measures in the concentration and Compactness Lemma
In the statement of the Concentration and Compacteness principle due P.L.Lions (https://ems.press/journals/rmi/articles/10756, Lemma I.1, page 158) it is said that the radon measure $\nu$ satisfies the relation
$$\nu = |u|^q + \sum_{j \in J}\nu_j\delta_{x_j},$$
where $(\nu_j)_{j \in J} \subset (0,\infty)$, $(x_j)_{j \in J}$ are distinct point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta_{x_j}$ is the Dirac mass at $x_j$. I want to understand what this equality means and how can I calculate the measure of a borel set using it. For example, if I want to calculate the measure of the set $B_{1}(x_i) = ${$x \in \mathbb{R}^n;|x-x_0| < 1\}$, assuming that $x_j \not\in B_1(x_i)$ for $i\neq j$, would it be given by
$$\nu(B_1(x_i)) = \int_{R^n}|u|^q dx + \sum_{j \in J}\nu_j\delta_{x_j}(B_1(x_i)) = \int_{R^n}|u|^q dx + \nu_i,$$
because $\delta_{x_j}(B_1(x_i)) = 0$, for $i\neq j$? What is the definition of $\eta =\sum_{j \in J}\nu_j\delta_{x_j}$? Would it be $\eta(A) = \sum_{j \in J}\nu_j\delta_{x_j}(A)$, where is a borel set? And what is the definition of $|u|^q?$ Would it be a notation for $\overline{\mu}(A) = \int_{A} |u|^q dx$ or a notation for $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u|^q$?
